# meteor upload a file to mongodb

Tags: html, mongodb, meteor, html5-audio

I am trying to find a way to upload an mp3 file into a mongo collection through my meteor collection. Its a bit challenging as I end up with "C:\fakepath\audio.mp3" as what is saved in the collection.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [FSCollection Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687779/meteor-upload-a-file-to-mongodb), and the `GridFS` Storage Adapter.

to get started run this on the console.

```
meteor add cfs:standard-packages

meteor add cfs:gridfs
```

now With fsCollection you can upload files simple as.

First

Declare the Collection.

```
AudioCollection = new FS.Collection("AudioCollection", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("AudioCollection")]
});
```

Create a simple `Event handler`.

```
Template.example.events({
  'click #example':function(e,t){
    //Simple Event to upload files into mongo.
  }
})
```

And do a simple `helper`

```
Template.example.helpers({
 showAudio:function(){
   return AudioCollection.find();
  }
})
```

With this **HTML**

```
{{each showAudio}}
  {{#if isAudio}}
   <!-- show whatever you want here -->
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Since the README its empty at this moment i made a sample [DEMO](http://demo.fscollection.meteor.com).

Comment: Thanks! works! Since you seem to know your stuff and there isn't much out there... Is there a way I can control helpers from my events?