# Storing different file types using Meteor.js and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I am a Computing Science student and I am doing my graduation project with Meteor.js. I am developing a web application where users could upload images, audio files and formatted text. My question is:

What is currently the most appropriate tool for that? If I am going to use CollectionFS how does it store the files?

Does it make sense to store each file type in separate collections (images, audio, text) or it makes more sense to just have field where I could specify it (e.g. type: audio)?

I kind of understand how GridFS does the file storage in a separate collection as chunking but I need a straightforward way to explain it in my project proposal because my supervisor is not really familiar with Meteor or MongoDB.

Comment: There are several [storage adapter](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#storage-adapters) options (disk, database, S3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824441/how-to-store-files-into-meteorapp/28824563#28824563) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687779/meteor-upload-a-file-to-mongodb/28687862#28687862) about this.

I try to made a little [DEMO](http://demo.fscollection.meteor.com) about this, check out the [Source Code](https://github.com/Ethaan/simple-uploadFS), into the demo there are little explainer about how to make it works (the fsCollection uploader).